# Rails devise case statement to if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, switch-statement

In my application controller I have a `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` method to alter the signin route after a user or admin signs in.

I want to alter the user sign in route depending if they have any current posts, though I can't get it to work as a case statement nor with an if statement.This is what I currently have and it works;

```
     def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
       case resource
       when Admin then admin_root_path
       when User then root_url
       end
    end
```

but I want to change it to an if statement like this (or case statement if easier), but this doesn't work...

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   if resource == User
     if current_user.posts.count == 1
       post_path(1)
     else
       root_url
     end
  elsif resource == Admin
    admin_root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: and by doesn't work you mean? (what error do you receive, or what is the behaviour)

Comment: try `if resource.is_a?(User)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby, the case statement uses the [case equality operator ===](http://ruby.about.com/od/control/a/The-Case-Equality-Operator.htm).  Consider the following code

```
>> User.new === User # false
>> User === User.new # true
>> User.new.is_a?(User) # true
```

`case` uses the second code to check for equality.  Knowing this, you can change your code to

```
if resource.is_a?(User)
  ...
elsif resource.is_a?(Admin)
  ...
end
```

You can also use `===` but `is_a?` is more readable

```
if User === resource
  ...
elsif Admin === resource
  ...
end
```

There's another way to do this and that is by getting the class of the resource

```
if resource.class.name == 'User'
```

Be warned though if you're using inheritance

```
class Foo; end
class Bar < Foo; end

bar = Bar.new

bar.is_a?(Foo) # true
Foo === bar # true
```